# Sending multiple arrays to a web worker -> The object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript

I have 4 numeric Javascript arrays, these are called, latitude_array, longitude_array, camera_angle_array and time_array.

I simply wish to pass these to a web worker, do some processing on them and retrieve them.

I am finding there is a huge overhead with my current approach, which is to send the arrays using:

```
var arrays_to_pass = [latitude_array, longitude_array, camera_angle_array, time_array];
thin_data_worker.postMessage(arrays_to_pass);
```

And then the reverse to retrieve them from the web worker.

I would like to use **Transferable Objects** instead to pass the 4 arrays over to the worker and get them back to speed this up.

I clearly don't understand web workers however, as I have attempted to do the following:

```
var object = {latitude:latitude_array, longitude:longitude_array, camera_angle:camera_angle_array,time:time_array}; 
thin_data_worker.postMessage(object, [object.latitude, object.longitude, object.camera_angle, object.time]);
```

But in Firefox I get the error 'The object could not be cloned'.

The web worker is attempting to retrieve the arrays using:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var latitude_array = e.data.latitude;
  var longitude_array = e.data.longitude;
  var camera_angle_array = e.data.camera_angle;
  var time_array = e.data.time;
)};
```

How can I pass these 4 arrays (and get them back) from a web worker?

Comment: Can you please share your JS file mapped to worker?

Comment: I have added this, though I believe the error may be caused during the call process

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to attach event handler for 'message' event.It is by default handled.

By looking your code,What I understand is you trying to create [dedicated worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Dedicated_workers).

You can do it in this way.

First create worker.js file and stored it.

Here is the worker.js

```
onmessage = function(fromConsumer){
    console.log(fromConsumer.data); //Will print the passed array 
    postMessage("I am sending the data  to consumer.");
}
```

Then from the script where you are creating the worker,create worker object.

```
 var my = new Worker('path_to_worker_js/worker.js');

 my.postMessage([1,2,4]);  // sending the array

 my.onmessage = function(dataFromWorker){

      console.log(dataFromWorker); //From consumer
 }
```

Here in this script,
you created `my` object and sending the data with the help of `postMessage` method.
Then in worker.js,we listening the `onmessage` event and get the passed data using parameter like `fromConsumer.data`.Again from here we sending the data to consumer using `postMessage`.

Now this time we have listen the `onmessage` event on worker object like `my.onmessage`

You can read more [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

UPDATE :

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

> Data passed between the main page and workers is copied, not shared. Objects are serialized as they're handed to the worker, and subsequently, de-serialized on the other end. The page and worker do not share the same instance, so the end result is that a duplicate is created on each end. Most browsers implement this feature as structured cloning.

Comment: I'm afraid this is what I am already doing, and this isn't using Transferable Objects, its cloning the array as I understand it, which is where my overhead is that I want to avoid

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, which is the reason I asked my question in the first place.  Transferable Objects do not work this way apparently.  I need to know how to use a Transferable Object to pass the data.